# How do I remove the commas, quotes, and parentheses from an exported python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, export

You guys were super helpful with my last newbie question so I figured I would give it another shot.  Right now, my Python 3 code takes data from a CSV file, stores the data as a list, creates permutations of that data, and exports it back out into a new csv file in a column format.  Unfortunately, the format of the exported list is not the best for what I need it for.  My question is: How do I remove the commas, brackets, and parenthesis from the exported list in python?

**How it Looks Now:**

('Hello', 'World', 'How')

('Hello', 'World', 'Are')

('Hello', 'How', 'World')

**How I would like it to look:**

Hello World How

Hello World Are

Hello How World

Here is the code I am using, does anyone have any advice or suggestions?  I am trying to learn so any extra insight would be much appreciated!

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('/users/Desktop/pythondata.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   J = []
   for row in reader:
      J.extend(row)
C = list(itertools.permutations(J, 3))
with open('THISISATEST.csv','w')as f:
   writer=csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n')
   for val in C:
       writer.writerow([val])`
```

P.S. -- Please forgive me if this is not formatted correctly, I am new to the board!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your question:

I recommend that you just use the `join` method to get the single string you are looking for. You could try:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as a_file:
    for result in C:
        result = ' '.join(result)
        a_file.write(result + '\n')
```

Basically, the `join` method called on a the string `' '` (a single space) will take each item in its argument (a single result from your permutations) and add them together in a single string separated by whatever that first string was (the single space). [This site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) gives a simple, illustrative example.

The `join` method is called with the syntax `'[separator]'.join([list of items to join])`, so if you just wanted to mash everything together into one string with no spaces, you could call it on an empty string: `''.join([my list])`.

Since you do not need a comma-separated file (CSV), you can simplify things by just using the `a_file.write` method as shown. If you use the CSV writer in this code you will get commas between every letter.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment.  I replaced both of the snippets of code as you recommended but received this error (any ideas?):                                                      **line 11, in <module> result = ' '.join(result)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found**

Comment: Do you know what version of Python you are using? It seems to work fine for me, but you might try `' '.join(item for item in result)`. You might also try ignoring the second part of my answer and tell me if that works. Also, the excellent point was made that you can just `f.writeline('\n'.join(' '.join(item for item in result) for result in C)` inside of that `with open(...)` section, and omit everything else.

Comment: I am using the most recent version of Python (3) -- my mistake I realize I should have added that to begin with.  My original question has been updated!

Comment: Did you try just making the first change in my answer and not the second? If you are still having trouble, could you post a short sample of your input data file so that i can test it using data that is structured the same way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried just the first part of your answer as well as every other part and I still get this error: **in <module>
    result = ' '.join(item for item in result)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found**.  My input data file is really just a test: it is a csv file and in column A of that file, there are five words (one in each cell) going down.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response Enginero -- thank you for the great work and help!  Very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are aware of regular expressions but using python's '[re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)' module should give you what you are looking for:

```
    import re
    strs = "('Hello', 'World', 'How')"

    #creates list of strings that match the regular expression
    words = re.findall(r"\'([A-Za-z]+)\'", strs)

    #joins all of the elements of the word array into a string separated by a space
    outputString = " ".join(words)

    #output is "Hello World How"
    print outputString
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tuples, there's an easier way. You don't need `csv` to export a space-delimited file.

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('pythondata.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    J = []
    for row in reader:
        J.extend(row)
C = itertools.permutations(J, 3)
with open('THISISATEST.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(' '.join(y for y in x) for x in C))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  I tried your code as well but received this error: **line 9, in <genexpr>
    f.write('\n'.join(' '.join(y for y in x) for x in C))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found**

Comment: I am using the most recent version of Python (3) -- my mistake I realize I should have added that to begin with.  My original question has been updated!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still searching for this as I was when try this, (python 3.x).
My aim was to list on separate lines all possible permutations of a 9 digit number.

the line `string = ''.join(str(char) for char in line)` was the winner

```
import sys, itertools

f = open('path to file', 'w') #I was using a .txt file

permutations = (list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 9)))

for line in permutations:
    string = ''.join(str(char) for char in line)
    f.write(string + '\n')            

f.close()
```