# removing square brackets and commas but not the commas in the sentence

Tags: python, string, file

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")

words = sentence.split()

position= [0]

for count, i in enumerate(words):

    if words.count(i) <2:

        position.append(max(position) +1)

    else:
        position.append(words.index(i) +1)

position.remove(0)

print (position)

words = str(words)

position = str(position)

file = open("list_and_positions_of_words.txt","w")

file.write (words +'\n') 

file.write(position)

file.close()
```

Example: Hello, what are you doing today?

My program will recreate the words to the positions so the output on the text file will be ['Hello,' 'what', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today?'] [1,2,3,4,5,6]

What I now need to do is take this file, open it and read it then print the original sentence including capital letters and punctuation(this wont be as a list).

Is there a way that I can remove the square brackets and commas but not the commas that are in the sentence, just the commas that separate the words as a list.

Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty important concept.  A list isn't just a string with extra characters in it.  It's a totally different way of storing data, and is recorded differently in the computers memory.  To concatenate a list of strings, do `''.join(list_of_strings)`

Comment: http://www.decalage.info/fr/python/print_list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the commas, quotes, and parentheses from an exported python list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925711/how-do-i-remove-the-commas-quotes-and-parentheses-from-an-exported-python-list)

Comment: what on earth is your `position` list suppose to represent? It certainly doesn't record the position of each word.....

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
file = "['Hello,', 'what', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today?'][1,2,3,4,5,6]"

start = ''.join(file).find('[') + 1
end = ''.join(file).find(']', start)
new_string = ''.join(file)[start:end]
original = new_string.rstrip("'").lstrip("'").replace("', '", " ")

print(original)
```

Good luck.